# How to update the contents of a file which consists of Headers in the first line and the values corresponding to it in the corresponding lines

Tags: python-3.x

I have a file with below contents:

```
pid int| name varchar(20)| price float

1      |Giga.            |10.99

2.     |PowerGiga.       |29.99
```

I want to replace Giga with Mega in the file where the column is Name
and replace price column <15 with 13.99
I have just written the contents given by the user input to a file. Its not stored with any mappings. How do you I replace the name in the file?

Expected:

```
pid int| name varchar(20)| price float

1      |Mega.            |13.99

2.     |PowerGiga.       |29.99
```

I have tried this with python as below .
Whats happening is, my entire file content is getting erased

```
import sys,re
import os
mypath="/Users/rk/Documents/code/PA1/"
db_used="CS457_PA2"
def updateTable():
        if os.path.isdir(mypath+db_used):

                filepath= mypath+db_used+"/"+filename+".txt"
                if not os.path.isfile(filepath):        #check if file not exists is true
                    print("!Failed to insert into table "+ filename +" because it does not exist.")
                else :
                    Column1=List[3]

                    Column2=List[6]

                    value1=List[4]

                    value2=List[7]
                    newfile=open(filepath, "r")

                    for w in newfile:
                        list= w.split('|')
                        if value1 in list:
                            print(list)
                            a=1
                            print("yes")
                            newfile=open(filepath, "w")
                            for a in list:
                                if value1 in list[0:]:

                                    newfile.write(a.replace(value1,value2))
                                    print("check the file if its updated")
                        else:
                            print("nothing")        


        else :
            db_used == " "
            print("DB is not selected")

user_says = input().strip() 
if "UPDATE" in user_says.upper():
            temp=user_says.strip(";")
            removespecial=re.sub("\W+", " ", temp) #removes special characters but preserves space
            List=removespecial.split(" ")
            filename=List[1]
            updateTable()

else:
    print("Debug")
```

> I tried the below code and it worked for me.

```
with open(filepath, "rt") as fin:
                        with open(out, "wt") as fout:
                            for line in fin:

                                fout.write(line.replace(value2, value1))
                            os.remove(filepath)
                            os.rename(out,filepath)
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried and describe how it failed?

Comment: I have tried using python.Column1=List[3]
     
Column2=List[6]
     
value1=List[4]
     
value2=List[7]
     
with open(filepath, "r") as f:
wordlist = [line.split('|')[1] for line in f]
     
if value1 in wordlist:
newfile= open(filepath, "a")
op=[w.replace(value1,value2) for w in wordlist]
print(op)
print("yes")
else: 
      print(wordlist)

Comment: I have tried using python. First when I run my main code, I will be creating File and writing the contents to it. When I receive update user input, Im trying to save the input by splitting and removing the special characters in the input Column1=List[3]
     
Column2=List[6]
     
value1=List[4]
     
value2=List[7]
     
with open(filepath, "r") as f:
wordlist = [line.split('|')[1] for line in f]
     
if value1 in wordlist:
newfile= open(filepath, "a")
op=[w.replace(value1,value2) for w in wordlist]
print(op)
print("yes")
else: 
print(wordlist)

Comment: You'll want to edit that into your question.

Comment: You're attempting to read and write to the same file simultaneously. While not impossible, this requires a lot of care and a decent knowledge of how file I/O works at lower levels. I'd recommend either reading the entire file into memory first (e.g. with something like `readlines()`), or writing to a temporary file and then finishing by moving the temp file to replace the original. Also, you'll want to read the [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) documentation to learn what the various modes do; `w` truncates the file.

Comment: Thanks.. I tried this out as you sais, and it worked..